# How to restore split fusion drive backup to fusion drive

Tags: macos, time-machine, catalina, imac, fusion-drive

My second hand iMac 2017 retina 5k running OSX Catalina has always had a split fusion drive as seen in image attached and I have been using it like that for ages and backing up via time machine to anexternal drive.

Now I want to reset the fusion drive (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584) but once I do the fresh Catelina install and try to restore from time machine are there going to be issues? Eg backup is of split fusion drive and now there is a fusion drive. I assume not but wonder if anyone has done this and can help?

Thanks in advance.

`diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Main Disk 2             27.6 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1000.0 GB  disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Main Disk — Data        273.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.8 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                529.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      21.5 GB    disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Main Disk               11.1 GB    disk2s5
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please amend your question to include the output from `diskutil list`, as that is a lot more detailed than the Disk Utility UI, and will go a long way to helping someone answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @AndyGriffiths i have edited to include that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running everything - OS, apps, user files - from the hard drive, and not using the SSD at all.

If that's the case, then your Mac will be ***very slow***. The whole purpose of the Fusion Drive is to mix the speed of an SSD with the storage size of the HDD.

However: your iMac is now 5 years old, and the average lifespan of a hard drive is ... 5 years! There is a high chance that the internal HDD will fail at some point soon. If you make a Fusion drive, and the hard drive part fails, then the whole format will be 'broken' -- the SSD portion will be completely blank (until you re-partition it).

In short, I would recommend getting a USB 3 high speed external SSD, and abandoning the internal drives.

Comment: I'll look to get a 1.0TB OWC Envoy Pro SX